# Flask SqlAlchemy получить количество записей из связи один ко многим?

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть две базы, одна проекты другая отклики к ним:

```
class Projects(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    publication_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now(), onupdate=datetime.now())
    term = db.Column(db.Integer)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    task = db.Column(db.Text)
    state = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    scope = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('spec.id'))
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order_status.id'), default=1)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    scope_admin = db.relationship('Spec', foreign_keys=[scope])
    status_admin = db.relationship('OrderStatus', foreign_keys=[status])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class Bid(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True)
    days = db.Column(db.Integer)
    message = db.Column(db.Text)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('user_current', uselist=False))
    project = db.relationship('Projects', backref=db.backref('project_current', uselist=False))

    def __init__(self, days, message, project_id, user_id):
        self.days = days
        self.message = message
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.time = datetime.now()
```

Проекты вывожу таким образом:

```
projects = Projects.query.order_by(Projects.id.desc()).paginate(page, POST_PER_PAGE, False)
```

Отображение:

```
{% for p in projects.items %}
    <div class="project_intro">
        <h2><a href="/project/{{ p.id }}">{{ p.title }}</a></h2>
        <span class="cat_date">{{ p.scope_admin }} | {{ p.publication_date.strftime('%d.%m.%y') }} в {{ p.publication_date.strftime('%H:%M') }} </span>
        <span class="time">{{ p.term }}</span>
        <span class="cat">{{ p.scope_admin }}</span>
        <span class="status {% if p.status == 2-%} in_work {%- endif -%}
                            {%- if p.status == 3 -%} work_end {%- endif -%}">{{ p.status_admin }}</span>
        <span class="freelansers">1 (+1)</span>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

Вопрос каким образом можно вывести количество откликов?

Дергать каждый раз цикле бд не вижу целесообразным, другого выхода придумать не могу, может надо сделать какой-то хитрый запрос?

Answer (score 1):

Делается так:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import func

projects = Session.query(Projects, coalesce(func.count(Bid.id), 0).label('clicks_count')).outerjoin(Bid, Bid.project_id == Projects.id)
```

Честно говоря, не юзаю `ForeignKey`, поэтому, наверное, условие для `outerjoin` можно не прописывать

Во вьюхе цикл будет такой:

```
{% for p, count in projects.items %}
...
```